# Docker container unable to access local host with specific port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cypress, vue-cli

In advance, my docker skills aren't great so apologies if the answer is blatantly obvious.

**TLDR:** Locally run website which I need to specify the port to access, how do I allow a docker container to access that website?

**More info:**

I have two websites that I run locally:

- The first is localapp.company.com that is an IIS site
- The other is localnewapp.company.com that is run locally by `vue-cli-service serve` and can only be accessed by specifying the port `localnewapp.company.com:8081`

I'm trying to parallelize our cypress tests via docker containers
where `{IPv4_ADDRESS}` = My local IP Address, here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
  cypress:
    build: .
    working_dir: /e2e
    extra_hosts:
       localnewapp.company.com: {IPv4_ADDRESS}
       localapp.company.com: {IPv4_ADDRESS}
    entrypoint: cypress run --headless --browser chrome --config-file ./cypress.json --record --key {KEY} --parallel --ci-build-id ${GITHUB_RUN_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./:/e2e
```

Cypress can run the tests that are for localapp but fail for localnewapp.

Using the Docker CLI, I've attempted to run:

- `curl localapp.company.com` which returns a valid response.
- `curl localnewapp.company.com:8081` fails to connect.

Not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated.

---

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, locally, port 8081 is in use by `node.exe` which is serving the website locally.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to expose a port from your `cypress` service

```
ports:
- HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT
```

like:

```
version: '3.2' 
  services:
    cypress:
      ..
      volumes:
      - ./:/e2e
      ports:
      - 8081:8080
```

see the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

Comment: Thanks @dnltinney, I've tried that and am getting the following error: `Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8081: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`

Comment: Most likely the port `8081` is in use. You can verify this via `nc -zv localhost 8081`. Have you tried a differen port ?

Comment: Port 8081 is in use by localnewapp.company.com which is run locally via the command `vue-cli-service serve` so it's in use with `node.exe`